# tabular inside a newcommand

Tags: macros, tables

I'm trying to define a \newcommand that has a tabular in it, but I get an:

```
! You can't use `macro parameter character #' in restricted horizontal mode.
```

Here's an example:

```
\newcommand{\Mytest}{1}{
\begin{tabular}{c}
    #1 \\\hline
\end{tabular}
}
```

Any way around this?

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce your error. Could please provide a *full* [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Arguments of a command should be enclosed in `[]` and not `{}`.

```
\newcommand{\Mytest}[1]{%
\begin{tabular}{c}
    #1 \\\hline
\end{tabular}%
}
```