# Tabular macro does not work

Tags: tables, macros

i try to write a short macro to align some (3) words one below the other in one cell of a table, like here: [tabular inside a newcommand](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25858/tabular-inside-a-newcommand)
For a reason I do not understand it does not work.
Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{censor}
\usepackage[a4paper, left=3cm, right=2cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

%my command to create the tabular
\newcommand{\cellincell}[3]{
\begin{tabular}{l}
#1 \\
#2 \\
#3 \\
\end{tabular}
}

\begin{document}

%only writes 'test1,test2,test3' plain in one line
\cellincell{test1,test2,test3}

%works as intended
%\begin{tabular}{l}
%test1 \\
%test2 \\
%test3 \\
%\end{tabular}



\begin{table}
\caption{this is how it should look like}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
Trimround & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{I} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{II} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{III} \\ \hline
number & \begin{tabular}{l}
test1 \\
test2 \\
test3 \\
\end{tabular} & text &  \\ \hline

\end{tabular}
\end{table}

%throws: ! Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr. (l. 56)
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
Trimround & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{I} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{II} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{III} \\ \hline
%number & \cellincell{test1,test2,test3} & text &  \\ \hline

\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: you have defined the macro to take three arguments so `\cellincell{test1}{test2}{test3}` not `\cellincell{test1,test2,test3}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, I use a `\Centerstack` to construct `\cellincell`, and also manage the comma parsing.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{censor}
\usepackage[a4paper, left=3cm, right=2cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\setstackEOL{,}
\setstackgap{L}{\normalbaselineskip}
%my command to create the tabular
\def\cellincell#1{\Centerstack[l]{#1}}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
Trimround & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{I} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{II} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{III} \\ \hline
number & \cellincell{test1,test2a,test3} & text &  \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The macro takes three arguments, not one argument with a comma separated list.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{censor}
\usepackage[a4paper, left=3cm, right=2cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

%my command to create the tabular
\newcommand{\cellincell}[3]{%%%
\begin{tabular}{l}
#1 \\
#2 \\
#3 \\
\end{tabular}%%%
}

\begin{document}

%only writes 'test1,test2,test3' plain in one line
\cellincell{test1}{test2}{test3}

%works as intended
%\begin{tabular}{l}
%test1 \\
%test2 \\
%test3 \\
%\end{tabular}



\begin{table}
\caption{this is how it should look like}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
Trimround & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{I} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{II} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{III} \\ \hline
number & \begin{tabular}{l}
test1 \\
test2 \\
test3 \\
\end{tabular} & text &  \\ \hline

\end{tabular}
\end{table}

%throws: ! Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr. (l. 56)
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
Trimround & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{I} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{II} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{III} \\ \hline
number & \cellincell{test1}{test2}{test3} & text &  \\ \hline

\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 for usage of `%%%`

Comment: @egreg: What's special about `%%%`?

Comment: @twip Inner joke, don't worry!

Comment: @twip It's a joke between me and David: he maintains that my best skill in TeX is finding missing `%` at end of lines; he uses three of them just to be sure he doesn't miss one. `;-)`

Answer (score 2):

`\cellincell` takes *three* arguments

```
\cellincell{<first>}{<second>}{<third>}
```

and you've only supplied *one*

```
\cellincell{<first>}
```

So, instead of using `\cellincell{test1,test2,test3}` use `\cellincell{test1}{test2}{test3}`. You can also use the method below to update your macro to use the comma-separated format:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

%my command to create the tabular
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\cellincell}[1]{\expandafter\@cellincell#1\@nil}
\def\@cellincell#1,#2,#3\@nil{%
  \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
    #1 \\ #2 \\ #3
  \end{tabular}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\cellincell{test1,test2,test3}

\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|}
  \hline
  Trimround & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{I} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{II} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{III} \\
  \hline
  number & \cellincell{test1,test2,test3} & text & \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Just like in the case of supplying three separate arguments, you are forced to use at least two `,`s in the call to `\cellincell`, even though some may be empty. As in `\cellincell{,,last}`, or `\cellincell{one,,three}`, for example.